# hadoop/hive :File is getting transforming into a directory

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

**Question:** As you can see, in the output, input.txt has changed from being a file to being a directory. How is it possible? Does create table in hive behave differently under some circumstances?

I have the following simple shell script to run a hive/hadoop script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xv
hadoop fs -rmr /user/myloginname/input.txt
hadoop fs -put input.txt /user/myloginname/input.txt
hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/

hive -S -f hive_script.hql
hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/
```

The hive script itself just creates an external table

```
create table if not exists myitems (
                item_id string)
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/myloginname/input.txt';

select "Number of items in myitems table is ",count(*) from myitems;
```

The input.txt file itself is very simple

```
cat input.txt
  44910429
  44657920
  36129962
```

Output of shell script is as follows

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/myloginname/input.txt
+ hadoop fs -rmr /user/myloginname/input.txt
Deleted maprfs:/user/myloginname/input.txt
hadoop fs -put input.txt /user/myloginname/input.txt
+ hadoop fs -put input.txt /user/myloginname/input.txt
hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/
+ hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/
Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x   3 myloginname myloginname        550 2015-08-29 00:06 /user/myloginname/input.txt

hive -S -f hive_script.hql
+ hive -S -f hive_script.hql
This is *bfd-main*.
Number of items in myitems table is     0

hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/
+ hadoop fs -ls /user/myloginname/
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - myloginname myloginname          0 2015-08-29 00:06 /user/myloginname/input.txt
```

**Question:** As you can see, in the output, input.txt has changed from being a file to being a directory. How is it possible? Does create table behave differently under some circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are creating a managed table, hive will try to set your table path in two ways:

a) If you specify a path in location while creating your table then that path would be considered as the source **directory** and hive will fetch all the files under that directory to build the table

b) It will take default `/user/hive/warehouse` directory and suppose if your table name is employee then it creates /user/hive/warehouse/employee directory then you build your table with 'load data local inpath' and that filename would go under /user/hive/warehouse/emp/ directory.

So in your case you are telling hive that all source files to build your table are available under the directory `/user/myloginname/input.txt`. But when it starts creating the table it finds that the path is not a directory but a file. Hence it overwrites and creates a directory out of that. Since you have no source files present under that directory created by hive, your count returns 0.

Give your location as LOCATION `/user/myloginname`.

Comment: Kindly acccept the answer if you find it useful